# Should I put multiple containers or only one parent container in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Here for an example:

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- First child element -->
    <!-- Second child element -->
</div>
```

or:

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- First child element -->
</div>

<div class="container">
    <!-- Second child element -->
</div>
```

Now I want to know is it better to have only one parent .container or every element should have its own .container?

I am learning the bootstrap 5 and I wanna know what is a better approach to use container because in bootstrap you need a wrapping container.

Comment: You don't _need_ a container in Bootstrap. You use it when you need it. Both approaches are perfectly usable depending on situation.

Comment: It depends on what you are designing. If it's a Navbar then It will have multiple children inside the parent container. If You are building a Jumbotron Then You will Use a Single Parent Div and Inside text. Like that. Depends on your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally i would put a container around each of my main components on the site rather than the site as a whole. This would allow sections to breakout from the container if need be. for example:

```
<div class="container">
    contained
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    full width
</div>
<div class="container">
    contained
</div>
```

This would not be easily achievable if all elements were wrapped in a single container.